# Why we couldn't create container with abstract class?

Tags: c++, templates, containers

I tried to create vector of abstract class but it give me compile error. the code is :

```
    class Base 
    {
    public :
        int _b; 
        virtual void virtualFunc() = 0;
    };

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        std::vector<Base> vec;
    }
```

And the compile error I got is :

```
error C2259: 'B' : cannot instantiate abstract class due to following members:
'void B::virtualFunc(void)' : is abstract
```

1) I don't understand why I go the error is it because vector will try to call the constructor ? is it something to have with pass by value ?
2) Is it the same behavior for templates functions too?

Comment: You cannot create a vector of abstract classes just like you cannot create a single object that's an abstract class. C++ does not work this way. You can create a vectors of pointers to abstract class instances.

Comment: The std::vector<T> default ctor creates no elements.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN All `std::vector<T>` ctors create a vector capable of storing `T`. But here `T` is not something you can create or store.

Answer (score 5):

> 1) I don't understand why I go the error is it because vector will try
>   to call the constructor ?

Yes -- internally the vector needs to allocate an array of objects to hold your data, i.e. it is going to try to do something like:

```
this->dataItems = new Base[10];
```

... but it can't do that because Base is an abstract class and thus may not be instantiated directly (in an array, or anywhere else).  Hence the error.

> is it something to have with pass by value ?

Not directly, but if your aim is to have a vector of objects that are various subclasses of Base, then you might want to go with:

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Base> > vec;
```

... instead.  Then you can do e.g.:

```
vec.push_back(new Derived1());  // where Derived1 is a subclass of Base
vec.push_back(new Derived2());  // where Derived2 is another subclass of Base
vec[0]->virtualFunc();   // calls Derived1::virtualFunc()
vec[1]->virtualFunc();   // calls Derived2::virtualFunc()
```

This will work because the vector's internal array is just an array of smart-pointers (which are non-abstract and all of the same type).

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly instantiate an abstract class, therefore a vector of abstract class can't work.

However, if you insist, you can use pointer to do so.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> vec;
```

When unique_ptr goes out of scope, it will autmaticlly delete the memory for you.

Make sure you are using `unique_ptr` instead of raw pointer, then you wouldn't have to worry about memory deallocation.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not allow you to create one instance of an abstract class. So if you can't make one object, how would you make a container of objects?

Think of it this way. Animal is an abstraction. Dog is a type of animal, hence a subclass of Animal. Fido is a particular object of type Dog.

You could not make an object of type Animal without specifying whether it is a Dog, Cat, Elephant, or some other animal. So you can't make a zoo comprised of "Animal"'s, but you could have a zoo with a particular Elephant, a particle Tiger, a particular Gorilla, and so forth.

What you probably want is a container of pointers to Base.

```
std::vector< Base * > vec;
```

Or better yet, a container of **smart**-pointers to Base.

```
typedef std::shared_ptr< Base > BasePtr;
std::vector< BasePtr > vec;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce your error with your code.

The following compiles:

```
class Base
{
public :
   int _b;
   virtual void virtualFunc() = 0;
};

int main(int , char**)
{
   std::vector<Base> vec;
   return(0);
}
```

My compiler gives the following warning:

```
R02: dumy506.cc
rm -f dumy506
g++-5 -m64  -O3 -ggdb -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor -pedantic -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wunused -Woverloaded-virtual   -O0   dumy506.cc  -o dumy506  -L../../bag -lbag_i686 -lposix_i686 -lrt -pthread

dumy506.cc:15:11: warning: ‘class Base’ has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Wnon-virtual-dtor]
     class Base
```

---

I can clear this warning by adding a virtual dtor

```
class Base
{
public :
   virtual ~Base() = default;

   int _b;
   virtual void virtualFunc() = 0;
};

int main(int , char**)
{
     std::vector<Base> vec;
     return(0);
}
```

---

According to "http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector", the "Default constructor. Constructs an empty container."

This says your code should *not* attempt to create any elements.

---

The 'pure method' compile error only occurs when I try to instantiate an element to install into vec.

```
int main(int , char**)
{
   std::vector<Base> vec;
   Base b;                // <<< pure method error detected here
   vec.push_back(b);
   return(0);
}


dumy506.cc:31:12: error: cannot declare variable ‘b’ to be of abstract type ‘Base’
       Base b;
            ^
dumy506.cc:15:11: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Base’:
     class Base
           ^
dumy506.cc:22:21: note:     virtual void Base::virtualFunc()
        virtual void virtualFunc() = 0;
```

2017-July-22 update

Today, on my system, vec.reserve() triggered a memory allocation which fails because of the pure function.

Perhaps the OP's implementation (and 2 other answers?) attempt to allocate some minimal number(?) of elements during ctor, contrary to cppreference.com.

Perhaps cppreference.com is mistaken, or requirements are 'moving'.

end-update

---

> 1) I don't understand why I go[sic] the error is it because vector will try
>   to call the constructor ?

no.  An empty vector can be created. No B is instantiated.

> is it something to have with pass by value ?

I think not.

> 2) Is it the same behaviour for template functions too?

You have not yet described the behaviour of your posted code.

---

My system: Ubuntu 15.10, 64 bit

Compiler:

~$ g++-5 --version
g++-5 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-23ubuntu1~15.10) 5.2.1 20151028

Comment: I am profoundly indifferent as to whether the compiler should or should not complain about the ctor being provided an abstract type.  Clearly, the author will learn of the mistake when trying to use the vector.

Comment: update - On this implementation, vec.reserve(<some positive N>) triggers a memory allocation which fails because of the pure function.  Perhaps the OP's implementation (and 2 other answers) attempt to allocate some minimal number(?) of elements during ctor (contrary to cppreference.com)

Comment: "_Today, on my system, vec.reserve() triggered a memory allocation which fails because of the pure function_" Since when is reserve allowed to create `T` objects?

Answer (score 0):

The most basic requirement in **all containers** of `T` is that `T` is a value type, that **you can create an instance of it**.

*By definition*, no instance of an abstract class can be created by a declaration.

By definition, templates are meta functions and meta classes: they are instantiated by filling in the given template arguments. They are tools to create functions and classes, but they are not functions and classes. When a template argument that violates specification is used, an incorrect function or class will be generated, and the error message will show a stack of instanciation, somewhat like a postmortem dump of a process that called `abort()` can be examined to see the function call stack.

The exact nature of the error message depends on the implementation details of the container. *That's the very ugly nature of C++ templates.* It is essentially a high level macro language.